# How do I deal with the infimum to compute the norm of a bounded linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following example in my lecture notes:

**Let $X = C[0,1]$ be a vector space of continuous real functions on the interval $[0,1] $ with the sup norm and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and let $T:X\to Y$ be an operator  defined as $Tf=f(0) 
 \space\space\forall f \in X$
Prove that $T$ is a a bounded linear operator and find the norm if possible.**

The lineary is inmediate. For the boundedness
$\|Tf\|_Y =|Tf|=|f(0)|\leq \max_{[0,1]}|f(t)| = \|f\|_X$
from which it follows that T is bounded and $\|T\|\leq 1$

In particular   $\|T\|=1$, since for $f \equiv1$, $\|Tf\|_Y=|f(0)|=|1|=1=\|f\|_X$

**My definition of norm of a bounded linear operator is :**
Let $T:X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator  $\|T\|=\inf\{ C>0; \|Tx\|_Y \leq C\|x\|_X \space \forall x \in X  \}$ is the norm of $T$

**Can someone please help me understand why $\|T\|=1$  ?** I fail to see how when the inequality in the definition becomes an equality  for a particular value of $f$, the $\inf$  over the values of $C$ that defines the norm of the operator  becomes equal to the value of the constant $C$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\|Tf\| \leq C\|f\|$ for all $f$. Taking $f=1$ we get $1 \leq C$. Thus every element of the set $\{C: \|Tf\| \leq C\|f\|\, \forall f \}$ is greater than or equal to $1$. This implies that the infimum of the set is also greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: what if for other functions f I get that $ k \leq C$ with $k <1$ or $k>1$, then the inf  wouldn't be 1?

Comment: Read the the definition of the norm slowly. Take any element $C$ of the set whose infimum is $\|T\|$.  We want to show that $C \geq 1$. For the proof this fact there is no need to consider all possible $f$ because the inequality in the definition is **given to us** for all $f$. We are not proving the inequality $\|Tf\| \leq 1 \|f\|$. Your confusion is between what is given and what needs to be proved. @J.C.VegaO

Comment: So if I am getting this right , to conclude that $\|T\|=1$ you are using the fact $ ||T|| \leq 1$ and $ ||T|| \geq 1$, where the first one is obtained from the boundedness proof in my notes and the second one is obtained from your proof ?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Yes, that is exactly what I am doing.